# How to close a content area and remember it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

What I want to accomplish is to be able to close a content area in a website and then remember that it's been closed the next time that the user load the website.
This website is an example of what I exactly need to accomplish.
[**dailyworth.com**](http://www.dailyworth.com/)

Closing the window seem quite simple. You intercept the mouse click and with a jQuery function you change the "display" property of that area to "none". The tricky part is how to remember that the next time that the user open the website.

I've found some information around. For example this is an old answer to a similar question but the plugin linked doesn't exist anymore.
[Save html in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002617/save-html-in-cookie)
Here there is another possible [solution](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/)

I'm a bit confused: cookies or local storage? For such a simple function there must be a best practice that is commonly followed. What would you suggest?

Comment: you need to use a storage mechanism... either in client side using cookies/webstorage or in server if it is a user based system

Comment: Cookies. Local storage is not supported by old browser.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a bit confused: cookies or local storage?

Cookies and local storage are pretty much same thing. The difference is that cookies have been supported by browsers from 90s. Local storage is new [Javascript API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

Two differences comes up my mind:

- you can´t define expiration for localStorage data
- localStorage is clientside only

When writing new javascript app, its better to use new API instead of raw cookies because its easier to use. You can attach [cookie based fallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Compatibility) so your code works with old browers too.

**Edit:** I have been playing with standalone js too long so I didnt remember you dont have access to localStorage from server. So, if the div you want to hide, comes from server instead of javascript, you have to use cookie to hide it.